# Execute command if su to a certain user

Tags: bash, shell, su

If I enter `sudo su - Rorschach` and login as Rorscach. I would like a command to be executed automatically.

Such as `echo "Hello Rorschach"` or `cd ~`

Where do I put these scripts in order for them to be performed upon login of that user?

I am using an ubuntu 14.04 command line and `echo $0` outputs `-bash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~/.bash_profile` (recommended) or `~/.bashrc` (will work, but this file should rather contain functions and aliases, not commands).

Answer (score 0):

As far as message after login is concerned you can write at `/etc/motd` file which I think is the recommended file.

`/etc/motd` is not a script but a text file which contents are shown before the first prompt of a login session.

motd: message of the day